# Error while deploying freqtrade ( binance error ) on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, binance, ccxt

I want to deploy the freqtrade bot on pythonanywhere, I installed the requirements then I run the api with a command in the pythonanywhere's console.
But i have the following error :

```
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair BRD/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair LINK/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair ALGO/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair BAT/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,447 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,447 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair ETH/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
```

I tried to make the get request in browser and it worked. So I don't understand what's wrong with that ...

Here's an other way to see the error :

```
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair BRD/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair LINK/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair ALGO/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,446 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair BAT/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
2021-05-24 12:16:27,447 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - retrying _async_get_candle_history() still for 4 times
2021-05-24 12:16:27,447 - freqtrade.exchange.common - WARNING - _async_get_candle_history() returned exception: "Could not fetch historical candle (OHLCV) data for pair ETH/BTC due to ExchangeNotAvailable. Message: binance GET api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
```

PS : I'm open to another deployment method

Thank you in advance !

Comment: It's possible that you need to configure proxy for `freqtrade` on PythonAnywhere, see [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !